# Change passwords for schedule Tasks Daily

Tags: active-directory, powershell, domain-controller, scheduled-task

I need to schedule a health check script on a particular domain controller , have the service account, everything works. Unfortunately due to firewalls, this script can only be run on a DC, which isn't ideal; but to compensate for that, i would like to change the password for service account daily.So my question is , how can i change the the creds for schedule task, with the same automated script?

Also are there any alternatives? since this crosses forest boundaries, i am not MSA is an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Windows 2012 then you should be able to use a Group Managed Service account to accomplish this.

http://blogs.technet.com/b/askpfeplat/archive/2012/12/17/windows-server-2012-group-managed-service-accounts.aspx